# Disable or fix Jhipster Test packages

Tags: java, spring, testing, jakarta-ee, jhipster

I'm in trouble with Jhipster's test packages. I was wondering if I could disable them, even if I know it's better to fix them.

In any case, I show you my problem, I hope to receive some help to fix this.

I've just finished to code a Jhipster webapp. I ran the application in test mode, using `main()` class. All seem to work perfectly, but when I try to build it I get 12 failed tests and 1 error.

Stacktrace:

```
Failed tests: 
DeskResourceIntTest.createDesk:113 Status expected:<201> but was:<500>
DeskResourceIntTest.deleteDesk:234 Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
DeskResourceIntTest.updateDesk:196 Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
DeskResourceIntTest.updateNonExistingDesk:217 Status expected:<201> but was:<500>
EventResourceIntTest.createEvent:111 Status expected:<201> but was:<500>
EventResourceIntTest.deleteEvent:238 Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
EventResourceIntTest.updateEvent:199 Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
EventResourceIntTest.updateNonExistingEvent:221 Status expected:<201> but was:<500>
UserResourceIntTest.createUser:170 Status expected:<201> but was:<500>
UserResourceIntTest.deleteUser:521 Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
UserResourceIntTest.updateUser:365 Status expected:<200> but was:<500>
UserResourceIntTest.updateUserLogin:409 Status expected:<200> but was:<500>

Tests in error: 
CustomUserResourceIntTest.initializationError »  Test class should have exactl...

Tests run: 146, Failures: 12, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

I obviously edited jhipster's generated classes, but at this point I don't know how to fix these problems to finally build and complete my app.

All failed tests fail at this code line:

```
restUserMockMvc.perform(put("/api/users")
        .contentType(TestUtil.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(managedUserVM)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

This is the situation for 12 failed tests, the method that throws the error is `.andExpect()`.

I edited `CustomUserResource.java`'s constructor in this mode:

```
public CustomUserResource(CustomUserRepository customUserRepository,
        UserRepository userRepository, UserService userService,
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, DeskRepository deskRepository, EventRepository eventRepository) {
    this.customUserRepository = customUserRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.userService = userService;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.deskRepository = deskRepository;
    this.eventRepository = eventRepository;
}
```

The same is `CustomUserResourceIntTest.java`:

```
public CustomUserResourceIntTest(CustomUserRepository customUserRepository, UserRepository userRepository,
        UserService userService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, 
        DeskRepository deskRepository, EventRepository eventRepository) {
    this.customUserRepository = customUserRepository;
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.userService = userService;
    this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.deskRepository = deskRepository;
    this.eventRepository = eventRepository;
}
```

The code line that throws error is this one:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    CustomUserResource customUserResource = new CustomUserResource(customUserRepository, userRepository, userService,
         passwordEncoder, deskRepository, eventRepository);
    this.restCustomUserMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(customUserResource)
        .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
        .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
        .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter).build();
}
```

Comment: `DeskResourceIntTest.createDesk:113 Status expected:<201> but was:<500>` means you had an internal server error, please post logs for the error.

Comment: If this is really what you want, you can disable all tests in maven with `mvnw -DskipTests` or just ignore the ones that are failing by annotating methods with `@Ignore("Don't know why it fails")`

Comment: I solved error tests regarding `InitializationError`. Other tests fail because of `AssertionErrors` stack trace doesn't say more.

Comment: For AssertionErrors, have you tried to run under debugger ?